# Flow into a tetrahedron

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

This problem is from Harold Edwards' *Advanced Calculus: A Differental Forms Approach*.  It is exercise $4c$ in section $1.3$.

> For a unit flow in the $z$-direction find the total flow *into* the tetrahedron with vertices $$P=(x_0,y_0,0),\quad Q=(x_1,y_1,0),\quad R=(x_2,y_2,0),\quad S=(0,0,1)$$ that is, find the flow across each of the four sides orienting them appropriately, and add.

Just checking: Don't I only need to find the flow into the bottom side (the side $PQR$) because the other sides will either have only flow out of them or no flow in or out of them?  I'm just trying to visualize this and it seems that I don't actually need to add the flow across the 4 sides.  I just need to find the flow across the bottom side.

So I'd think that the flow into the tetrahedron would just be given by $$\begin{align}\text{flow into tetra } &= \left.dxdy\right|_{PQR} \\ &= [\text{area of } PQR] \\ &=\frac 12[x_0(y_1-y_2)+x_1(y_2-y_0)+x_2(y_0-y_1)]\end{align}$$

Or am I misunderstanding something?

---

**Edit**:  OK.  After drawing some pictures and thinking about it a bit, I can see that the other sides could contribute depending on the points $P$, $Q$, and $R$.

But now I'm stuck with something else: In addition to the area of $PQR$ given above (which I should have taken the absolute value of), I think that the areas of the projections of the other three triangles are:

$$A_{PQS}=\frac 12 \left|-y_0(x_1-x_0)+x_0(y_1-y_0)\right| \\ A_{QRS}=\frac 12 \left|-y_1(x_2-x_1)+x_1(y_2-y_1)\right| \\ A_{PRS}=\frac 12 \left|-y_0(x_2-x_0)+x_0(y_2-y_0)\right|$$

BUT, I'm pretty sure at least one side has to be on the other side of the tetrahedron from the $xy$ plane.  And in fact all of them might be except the $PQR$ triangle.  So how do I determine in general what the flow *into* the tetrahedron will be?  It's going to the sum of some subset of these $4$ areas, but which ones depend on the points $P$, $Q$, and $R$ don't they?  So is there any general expression I can give for this?

This exercise seems way harder than all the other ones in the text up to this point.  I wonder if I'm somehow overthinking this?  Is there some simple trick I'm missing?

---

**Edit2**: To Amitai Yuval: are you saying the answer should just be zero?  Because that's what I'll get if I add the flow into and flow out of the tetrahedron.  Even if that's what I'm supposed to get, I still wouldn't know how to orient the sides as they depend on the relative arrangements of points $P$, $Q$, and $R$.

Comment: As written in the bottom line of the exercise, you should consider *all* faces, with the appropriate orientation.

Comment: Edwards' book has solutions at the end.  Flip to the back of the book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is 0 for exactly the reason you claim and the answer is at the back of the book.